# VBA Code Reading an Unprotected Workbook as Protected

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to run the below VBA code to cut data from A2 to the last row of each sheet and paste the values into a sheet named ASN; however, when Excel reads the "Copy data to target sheet" line it returns "Run-time error '1004': The cell or chart you're trying to change is on a protected sheet. To make a change, unprotect the sheet".

The workbook is an export from a web page so I'm not sure what the password could be or why it's protected - **my question: is there something wrong with my code that's prompting this error? follow up: is there a way to toggle protected viewing for files downloaded from the internet?**

```
Dim last_row As Long
    last_row = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Dim newRow As Long
        newRow = last_row + 1
    
    Dim destinationRange As Range
        Set destinationRange = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ASN").Range("A" & newRow)
        
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    
    'Loop through each source sheet
    For Each sourceSheet In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If sourceSheet.Name <> "ASN" Then  ' Skip target sheet
            
            ' Copy data to target sheet
            sourceSheet.Range("A2:J" & last_row).Cut destinationRange
                destinationRange.Offset(1, 0).Activate
            
        End If
    Next sourceSheet
```

Comment: If you go to the ASN sheet, click on the Review tab > Unprotect Sheet, does it ask you for a password? If you don't know the password, you can try copying everything from ASN to a new sheet like ASN2, and then change the macro to copy to ASN2.